# C# application - authenticate oracle database login using windows user credentials

Tags: c#, oracle, active-directory, ldap

Our Oracle Database environment is using Microsoft Active Directory as the LDAP directory. Hence, the Windows logon account and password are also the Oracle database's user account and password.

We are building a C#/.Net application that connects to the Oracle Database. Instead of prompting for User account / Password in the Application, is there a way to automatically authenticate  and connect to Oracle using the login credentials of the Windows user currently logged on?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to use single sign on or trusted authentication, native authentication etc. This is not the same as using the same username and password from AD. There is no way to get the current user's password programatically without prompting for it.